# jQuery ui Datepicker - global extend/override?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page using dozens of jQuery-UI's datepicker instances. Now I need to add additional functionality to the *beforeShowDay* function.

I thought, extending it would be the right way, until I found out it does not use the widget-factory, which makes extending quite hard in my case.

Is there any way to extend the logic..

- without touching each instantiation of the datepicker
- without touching the jquery-ui.js itself

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.extend($.ui.datepicker.prototype, {
        beforeShowDay: function(d) {
            console.log(d);
        }
    });
});
```

That does not result in js-errors, even though it does not log anything in console on opening a datepicker the common way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `beforeShowDay` in `$.datepicker._defaults` which is `null` by default. So,

```
$.datepicker._defaults.beforeShowDay = function(date){
    console.log(date);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: THAT was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!